# Wrong material on objects

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

I have this scene, some of the objects (tables, cabinet..) don't have correct color and I don't know why. I think the problem is in the front/back face of the objects, but don't know how to correct it.

Tables should be same material as chairs.

This is with `glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);`
[image]

This is with `glColorMaterial(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);`
[image]

I want the tables be same as the chairs, correct color is in the first picture.

my init:

```
void init(){
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    GLfloat ambientColor[] = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    GLfloat diffuseColor[] = { 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1 };
    GLfloat specularColor[] = { 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1 };
    GLfloat lightPosition[] = { 1, 1, 0, 1};


    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambientColor);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseColor);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, specularColor);

    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);

}
```

Chair and table material:

```
void setChairMaterial(){
    GLfloat ambientChair[] = { 0.1745,0.01175,0.01175 };
    GLfloat diffuseChair[] = { 0.61424,0.04136,0.04136 };
    GLfloat specularChair[] = { 0.727811,0.626959,0.626959 };
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, ambientChair);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseChair);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, specularChair);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 0.6);
}
```

This function is called before every creation of chair and tables between `glPushAttrib(GL_LIGHTING_BIT)` and `glPopAttrib()`

Draw chair:

```
glPushMatrix();
glPushAttrib(GL_LIGHTING_BIT);
glTranslatef(8, 0, 8);
glRotatef(-90, 0, 1, 0);
glScalef(3, 3, 3);
setChairMaterial();
drawObj("chair.obj");
glPopAttrib();
glPopMatrix();
```

Draw table:

```
glPushMatrix();
glPushAttrib(GL_LIGHTING_BIT);
glTranslatef(5, 0, 18);
glScalef(0.05, 0.05, 0.05);
setChairMaterial();
drawObj("table.obj");
glPopAttrib();
glPopMatrix();
```

Function `drawObj(const char* path)` draws objects with `GL_TRIANGLES` and sets normals

Comment: It might help if you include the code you're using to actually draw the tables and chairs. If setChairMaterial is being called before you draw the chairs but there's something resetting the material before you draw the tables that might have something to do with it. The code you've posted is not awfully useful in determining this.
FYI the use of fixed-function commands like glMaterial is deprecated as well, you should ideally be using shaders for your materials.

Comment: @SeanBurton Added that parts! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
glScalef(3, 3, 3);
...
glScalef(0.05, 0.05, 0.05);
```

Careful with those.  [Scaling applies to normals too:](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/lights.htm#ligh0090)

> **The OpenGL specification needs normals to be unit length to achieve typical lighting results. The current ModelView matrix transforms normals. If that matrix contains a scale transformation, transformed normals might not be unit length, resulting in undesirable lighting problems.**
>
> OpenGL 1.1 lets you call glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE), which will make all normals unit length after they're transformed. This is often implemented with a square root and can be expensive for geometry limited applications.
>
> Another solution, available in OpenGL 1.2 (and as an extension to many 1.1 implementations), is glEnable(GL_RESCALE_NORMAL). Rather than making normals unit length by computing a square root, GL_RESCALE_NORMAL multiplies the transformed normal by a scale factor. If the original normals are unit length, and the ModelView matrix contains uniform scaling, this multiplication will restore the normals to unit length.
>
> If the ModelView matrix contains nonuniform scaling, GL_NORMALIZE is the preferred solution.